# Bmw lights random turn on at night

Tags: car, bmw, mechanics-trade

Light turn on randomly at night help https://youtu.be/Anxs2ciMMpY

Help !!!

Comment: This has been asked before... did you look? But one possibility is shutting a bug inside the car...

Comment: I have checked and no bugs in the car I believe it could be the light control unit or a relay ?

Comment: Interesting to see that your brake lights are on as well, with no one in the car.